# Get file from RESW resource

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have encountered a problem with retrieving a file for RESW file.

My project structure:

- Levels

  - Level1.xml
  - Level2.xml
  - Level3.xml
- Resources

  - LevelResources.resw

And files from "Levels" directory are added to "LevelResources.resw".

My try to retrieve content of those files:

```
var resourcesLoader = new ResourceLoader("LevelResources");
var item = resourcesLoader.GetString("Level1");
```

But the value of "item" is"

> ..\levels\level1.xml;System.String, System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03g5f6f12d40a6a;windows-1250

Why? This is not exactly what I expected (content of the file). How to retrieve content than?

Answer (score 1):

The ResourceLoader class provides simplified access to app resources such as app UI strings.

When you dragging a file to the resource file, the data was stored as a file reference rather than the content, that’s why you will get result “level1.xml;System.String...”.
As a recommend way, I suggest you putting the file name as the key and the file content as the value in the *resw file so that you can use the ResourceLoader to get the content easily.